# how to export the monocle data into Seurat

Tags: seurat, single-cell, monocle

I have tried to export the monocle data into Seurat and got the error

```
"Error in Seurat::CreateSeuratObject(raw.data = data, normalization.method = "LogNormalize",  :
  unused arguments (raw.data = data, normalization.method = "LogNormalize", do.scale = TRUE, do.center = TRUE, is.expr = monocle_cds@lowerDetectionLimit)
Calls: exportCDS
In addition: Warning message:
In if (export_to == "Seurat") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
```

Here is my code `seurat_SAN_cds_subset <- exportCDS(SAN_cds_subset)`

Is anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no default for the `export_to` option, so you just need to specify `export_to="Seurat"`. Note that monocle2 doesn't seem to be compatible with the newest Seurat (3.1) releases.

Comment: It is possible to update Seurat v2 objects to Seurat v3 objects via `UpdateSeuratObject()`.

Comment: I don’t know off hand, maybe give it a whirl and see.